# strtotime() function not working in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, strtotime

I wrote a line to convert the date entered from a view to be converted into date format in the database. But the function is not working (PHP version 5.4). Here's the code;

```
$chq_date = $_POST['cheque_date'];
echo $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($chq_date));
```

The value obtained for `$chq_date` is `24/01/2014`, but then the `$date` is showing the result `1970-01-01`. How does this happens? What is wrong with the script?
If someone could please help me out..

Comment: Maybe strtotime doesn't recognize the date format dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace "/" by "-" to get the correct format

```
$chq_date = str_replace('/', '-', $chq_date );
echo $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($chq_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

change the accpeted date format to: (value for $_POST['cheque_date'])

```
24-01-2014
```

remove **/**  and add **-**  in dates... then you will get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
$chq_date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['cheque_date'];);
echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($chq_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chq_date = str_replace("/","-","24/01/2014");
echo $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($chq_date));
```

this is the format to use **strtotime()**. So for Your example , You use below:-

```
$chq_date = str_replace("/","-",$_POST['cheque_date']);
echo $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($chq_date));
```

if the separator in Your **$_POST['cheque_date']** is **/** otherwise use proper separator. check [here](https://www.php.net/str_replace) for more details on **str_replace()**.

Answer (score 0):

Your giving date format as `DD/MM/YYYY`
It must be as `MM/DD/YYYY`

```
$chq_date = "11/13/14";
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime($chq_date));
```